# How to test a Loading Indicator with coroutines (TestCoroutineScope is deprecated)?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I am following [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-survey#4) but it seems to be outdated. `TestCoroutineScope` is deprecated.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()):
    TestWatcher(),
    TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

I've been trying to reproduce the following test

```
@Test
fun loadTasks_loading() {
    // Pause dispatcher so you can verify initial values.
    mainCoroutineRule.pauseDispatcher()

    // Load the task in the view model.
    statisticsViewModel.refresh()

    // Then assert that the progress indicator is shown.
    assertThat(statisticsViewModel.dataLoading.getOrAwaitValue(), `is`(true))

    // Execute pending coroutines actions.
    mainCoroutineRule.resumeDispatcher()

    // Then assert that the progress indicator is hidden.
    assertThat(statisticsViewModel.dataLoading.getOrAwaitValue(), `is`(false))
}
```

but I'm having no success. I don't know how to pause a dispatcher now.

How can I do that in the new way?

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer here: [Migrating to the new coroutines 1.6 test APIs by Marton Braun](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-the-new-coroutines-1-6-test-apis-b99f7fc47774)

```
@get:Rule
val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

@Test
fun loadTasks_loading() = runTest {
    // Main dispatcher will not run coroutines eagerly for this test
    Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())

    // Load the task in the ViewModel
    statisticsViewModel.refresh()

    // Validate progress indicator is shown
    assertThat(statisticsViewModel.dataLoading.getOrAwaitValue()).isTrue()

    // Execute pending coroutine actions
    // Wait until coroutine in statisticsViewModel.refresh() complete 
    advanceUntilIdle()

    // Validate progress indicator is hidden
    assertThat(statisticsViewModel.dataLoading.getOrAwaitValue()).isFalse()
}
```

MainDispatcherRule

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainDispatcherRule(
        val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    ) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the deprecated `TestCoroutineDispatcher` you should see this pop up:

[image]

`@Deprecated("The execution order of TestCoroutineDispatcher can be confusing, and the mechanism of pausing is typically misunderstood. Please use StandardTestDispatcher or UnconfinedTestDispatcher instead.", level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING)`

So the solution here is to use `StandardTestDispatcher` or `UnconfinedTestDispatcher`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've done that, but there is no method to pause the dispatcher. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: I don't think it is allowed any more, this link shows the migration guide for using test dispatchers, the section I have linked shows the migration when using pauseDispatcher https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md#replace-usages-of-pausedispatcher-and-resumedispatcher-with-a-standardtestdispatcher